# Entity framework query completed event

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

So my Question is: Is there a Query completed event???

I am using entity framework in order to query some data from a database and display it in a WPF application. My problem is that rendering finishes before entity framework has received the results from the database server, thus my list of data on the UI remains empty. In contrast if I enter debug mode and just wait a little before moving on to list the data, the query finishes and the data gets 
listed.

How should I approach this Problem??

**EDIT:**
Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseModel : DbContext, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> observableCollection;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Employee> ObservableEmployees
        {
            get
            {
                return observableCollection;
            }
            set
            {
                observableCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ObservableEmployees");
            }
        }

        public DatabaseModel()
        {
            ObservableEmployees = Employees.Local;
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

And how I use My DataBinding through WPF:
in App.Xaml I define an Instance of this Class...

```
<Application.Resources>
        <local_database:DatabaseModel x:Key="DatabaseInstance"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

And using the data in Mainwindow.XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DatabaseInstance}, Path=ObservableEmployees, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                             Binding.SourceUpdated="ListBox_SourceUpdated">
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Could you add some sample code to illustrate the problem. It sounds like you're doing things out of order if you're loading your interface before you've got the data.

Comment: Note that C# isn't asynchronous, so your code will work *continiously* as written in code. Show us some code and we will try to help you.

Comment: added some code for you guys...maybe that will help you help me:D

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your source.

1. You use `Employees.Local`, but I can't see any code that loads employees.
2. A view model derived from `DbContext` defeats the purpose of view models: separation of concerns. The view model should not be involved in data layer activities. You controller/presenter layer should create it *using* the data layer. In other words: create a `DatabaseModel` as POCO class and populate it with an `Employees` collection from the data layer. Then the view model gets populated before the UI starts rendering and you don't need any complicated wiring to wait for queries to complete.

Comment: I am using WPF not ASP.NET MVC... that is why I have two properties, one of type DbSet<Employees> and the other an observable collection(that is what WPF requires) to be able to bind a listview's itemsource to it ...

Comment: Oh...And database get queries(employees get loaded) when i create instance of DatabaseModel in XAMl file..see above

Comment: I know, but With WPF view models are just as useful. Just google WPF + MVVM. As for the loading: you have `ObservableEmployees = Employees.Local` but the local collection is empty when no query against `Employees` is executed.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something here as I am new to Entity Framework, but I wrote on top of page that if I enter debug mode and wait for 2,3 secs then everything works fine, the data gets passed to XAML file..that means that the query gets executed...also, the query is executed when an Instance of DatabaseModel is created...I am not sure how that works...but it's the "magic" of Entity framework as Scott Allen calls it...